# vaadin 14 upload a captured image from a smartphone

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm new to vaadin and I'm trying to upload an image to the server from a smartphone captured image.

I'm been using Spring Boot and the code rigth here : https://cookbook.vaadin.com/camera the image is successfully taked but I don't know how to configure a server directory path on an embembed tomcat server.

As I can read here https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-upload

The following example uploads images to /tmp/uploads directory in (UNIX) filesystem (the directory must exist or the upload fails). The component displays the uploaded image in an Image component.

I'm been running under Windows 10 so no upload directory, or do I've missed something.

I also tryed to configure this :

spring.http.multipart.location=C:/tmp

Thx in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by playing with this parameter :

spring.servlet.multipart.location=C:\Users\41786\skeleton-starter-flow-spring-14\skeleton-starter-flow-spring-14\

edit use double \